# DLL Reference pointing to Temp folder class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll

I'm having a class library which is getting referenced in a web application. This class library exists in the same solution. But when I add reference to this by `"using"` statement and try to use the class in my aspx page, after building the project, it refers to `"C:\Documents and Settings\user1\Temp"` location class file.

When I delete this class file and try to do a "`Go to Definition`" , it says `"Cannot navigate to ConfigReader class"`.

I tried all the options

1. by deleteing all debug (DLL files) and rebuilding the project but no luck.
2. By deleting the reference and again creating it and re-writing the using DLL code.

Please let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: Please have a look at the `.csproj` project file with a text editor (or via context menu in the Solution Explorer: Unload project, then Edit). What does the reference for the assembly look like? Does it contain a link to the temp path?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The <HintPath> refers to "..\Utils\bin\Debug\ConfigClass.DLL" But now it says "cannot Navigate to .." as I told.. but previously it was navigating and when doing "open Containing folder" it was pointing to temp folder.

Comment: If you do "Open containing folder", does the document title end with "[from metadata]". Then it would be no surprise that the temporarily created class is inside the temp folder. On top of that file should be a link to the referenced assembly (inside a region), what is it in your case?

Comment: Thanks Andre. Sorry for late reply. Yes it tells [from Metadata] But I didn't got what you meant by "On top of that file should be a link to the referenced assembly (inside a region)" How can we resolve this issue? since deleting and adding the reference back doesn't helps.

Comment: Did you add the reference in the solution explorer by right-clicking on "References", then on "Add Reference..." and selecting from the "Projects" tab? (You wrote that you added the reference by a `using` statement, that's not sufficient.

Comment: No Andre. I added the reference using "Browse" and selected the target DLL file from the classlibrary physical path. Is there anything wrong by doing this ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8586/discussion-between-andre-and-sayed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the assembly via the "Projects" tab in the "Add Reference..." dialog.